# Connecting Ground Paths of Low-Current and High-Current Circuits

Tags: current, ground, ground-plane

A small (3.3V/10mA) uC circuit requires a ground.  I designed the circuit’s PCB to use a nearby ground wire that is attached to the car’s frame in at least two places and used by the 2A windshield washer motor (other devices may use it as well).  I created a break in the ground wire (denoted by A and B) and it is soldered to the PCB onto two pads nearly touching and connected by a 100 mil trace (2 oz), more than adequate for the washer motor. (The trace width calculator indicates 8 A conservatively.)  Connecting the remaining ground wire C completes the uC circuit and everything works fine; the washer and the circuit.  Both are on the same 12V supply but I’m curious if there is anything inherently wrong with this approach.  Ideally, (from what I’ve read) I would add another separate ground wire for the uC circuit, but I would like to avoid adding another wire if at all possible.  The uC is only controlling a relay.  Should I isolate the A-B pads from the ground pour using a polygon cutout and then connect the uC circuit grounds to those pads with a single connection instead of having A and B directly connected to the ground pour?  Does it matter?

There are numerous threads about connecting grounds, but the many I've read address noise and different voltage potentials; I have not seen anything that addresses sharing a ground with another higher-current circuit.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fnvhQX.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Related: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/97198/why-does-connecting-a-high-current-device-to-my-digital-circuit-cause-weird-beha

Comment: I wonder why there is a wire running from the chassis to the 'metal dash'; I assume that it is not connected to the chassis in any other way?

Comment: @JvO The car is nearly 40 years old; there are very few non-conductive parts and the metal body is used extensively as a ground.  Some items don't even have a ground wire, per se, like the AM radio.  It has a 12V power wire and is bolted to the dash for the return path.  (My license plate lights didn't work until I realized some powder coating had broken the lights' ground path.)

Comment: @Matt Thanks for the link; very helpful.  Had not found that one in my searches.

Comment: Then the wire only seems redundant... Perhaps you were trying to save some wire but I'd recommend drawing a new ground wire from the closest metal car part to your PCB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this particular case, a single point ground from the microcontroller power return makes sense as it will tend to attenuate the *very noisy* motor power which could otherwise cause intermittent operation of the controller.

Grounding and power schemes in general have to be analysed on a case by case basis; there is no 'one size fits all'.